# Kubernetes Pod Creation Speed

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We would like to spin up pods quickly on our cluster, to handle 'one-off' tasks (the idea being that each task has a new pod every time it runs).

Currently, it takes about 10-15 seconds from a Pod creation API call -> completion. This is running on 3x m3 xlarge on AWS, with images that have already been cached (I presume, as I am using the same image twice on a single Node). We are running with restartPolicy = Never, as they are one off tasks.

I've tried fiddling with the imagePullPolicy (= Never) and resource options with no avail. It appears that the 10 second delay happens in the 'Running' phase, after Kubernetes has handed it off to a Pod. I can confirm the operation itself is very quick: running locally on Docker only takes about 0.5s total, including the operation.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: This may be a good question to open as an issue in the [Kubernetes bug tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/), or ask in the `#google-containers` IRC channel on Freenode.

Comment: Yes, taking the question to either of those places with more details of what's happening would be great. We'd love to help figure out why it's working so slowly! If you can, attach the logs from the kubelet (/var/log/kubelet.log) on the node the pod is scheduled on.

Comment: Thanks guys.. Done just that!

Comment: Does that 10-15s include downloading the image or is the image already locally available on that node?

Answer (score 1):

Our target is 5s latency from creation -> Running (assuming image is pre-pulled). The issue tracking this was https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/3954.

This issue was closed a couple weeks ago, so please update to version 20.2 and give it another try.